# trying to write a script that redirects to another page using data that was put in to a form

Tags: php

I am trying to write a script that redirect to another page using data that was put in to a form. Here is the script I have now.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="redirect.php?=sendtext">
<p>
<label for="Phone">Phone Number:&nbsp;</label>
<input type="text" name="Phone" id="Phone" />
</p>
<p>
<input name="submit" type="button" value="Text Coupon" />
</p>
</form>
<?php

$phone == $_GET['phone'];

if($_GET['form1'] == 'sendtext'){
    header("Location: www.head1stapparel.com/" . $phone . "");
    die();
} 
?>
```

It doesn't seem to work. Can someone give me some one please help? Thanks!

Here is the entire page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
$phone = $_POST['Phone'];

if($_GET['sendtext'] == 1){
header('Location: http://www.head1stapparel.com');
die();
} else {

?>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="redirect.php?sendtext=1">
<p>
<label for="Phone">Phone Number:&nbsp;</label>
<input type="text" name="Phone" id="Phone" />
</p>
<p>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Text Coupon" />
</p>
</form>
<? } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is there a reason why you're mixing GET with POST? It's hard for me to provide you with an answer/solution. If not, using POST is way easier, without the GET parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your code isn't working, is because you have output before header. You are masking the fact that PHP is throwing an error and in not displaying it.

- Using error reporting will confirm this.
- Consult my footnotes about this.

You will need to place your PHP above your HTML form.

**Sidenote #1:** I don't know what you want to achieve here, but if you plan on echoing anything under `header()`, you won't be able to; that is also considered as output.

Even a simple cookie, a byte order mark, a space before your opening PHP tag; nothing.

So, here is a rewrite with your PHP on top, followed by your HTML form.

- What you choose to do from hereon in, will be up to you.

**Sidenote #2:** FYI, forms do not bear a name attribute, yet I did leave it in your form tag.

```
<?php
$phone = $_POST['Phone'];

if($_GET['sendtext'] == 1){
header('Location: http://www.head1stapparel.com');
die();
} else {

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="redirect.php?sendtext=1">
<p>
<label for="Phone">Phone Number:&nbsp;</label>
<input type="text" name="Phone" id="Phone" />
</p>
<p>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Text Coupon" />
</p>
</form>
<? } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Foonotes:**

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

**Using your present formatted code:**

In order to use your presently formatted code, there may be a quick fix which does work at times but can also fail, is to use [`ob_start();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) at the top of your code, followed by the rest.

For example:

```
<?php 
ob_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

...
rest of your code
```

- As I said, this does not always work, but you can try it.
- As for `header("Location: www.head1stapparel.com/" . $phone . "");` well, you can incorporate that in your code somehow. I don't know what the ultimate goal is.
- `Location: www.head1stapparel.com/` that, should have an `http://` at the beginning.
- `header("Location: http://www.head1stapparel.com/" . $phone . "");`
- Consult the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Thank you for the explanation on the error. What I am actually trying to achieve is a redirect to a webpage using a variable (in this case the phone number) in the link. It is to send a coupon via text message. I actually used all of the advice here and re-wrote the script completely using a META refresh rather than a Php redirect. It seemed the better option for what I am trying to achieve.

Dreamweaver added the name attribute to the form.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the form to redirect.php so the php in your question must be placed there. 
Said this you should change your code to

```
<?php

$phone = $_POST['phone'];

if($_GET['action'] == 'sendtext'){
    header("Location: www.head1stapparel.com/" . $phone);
    die();
} 
?>
```

and your HTML:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="redirect.php?action=sendtext">
```

BTW you can post also the action value using:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="sendtext">
```

Comment: This did not work. I'm getting an error Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/head1sta/public_html/test/redirect.php:11) in /home/head1sta/public_html/test/redirect.php on line 23

Comment: If your page contains only the php as I suggested you you shouldn't get this error. This is received because you echo something before header() is executed. Can you post an update of your actual code so to help debugging?

Comment: I just did an edit and included the entire page. As I said no other code is on the page.

Comment: Ok. Let's try to explain: 1 place html in one page. 2 place php in a page and call it redirect.php. Open the first page, try to send the form and voila! You will never see the php page and you will get the redirect. Please note that with JavaScript on the first page you can get the same result without using the second page.

Comment: Btw check the url of the redirect: it is missing the phone part or it's a typo?

Answer (score 0):

Some error you have, see this..

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="redirect.php?sendtext=1">
<p>
<label for="Phone">Phone Number:&nbsp;</label>
<input type="text" name="Phone" id="Phone" />
</p>
<p>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Text Coupon" />
</p>
</form>
<?php
$phone = $_POST['Phone'];

if($_GET['sendtext'] == 1){
   header("Location: http://www.head1stapparel.com?phone=" . $phone . "");
    die();
} 
?>
```

Comment: Same thing here. Getting error

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/head1sta/public_html/test/redirect.php:11) in /home/head1sta/public_html/test/redirect.php on line 22

Answer (score 0):

Your output is send header information, and can't two time in same page, Try
redirect with JavaScript..

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="redirect.php?sendtext=1">
<p>
<label for="Phone">Phone Number:&nbsp;</label>
<input type="text" name="Phone" id="Phone" />
</p>
<p>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Text Coupon" />
</p>
</form>
<?php
$phone = $_POST['Phone'];

if($_GET['sendtext'] == 1){
   //header("Location: http://www.head1stapparel.com?phone=" . $phone . "");
   ?>
   <script>
    window.location.href = "http://www.head1stapparel.com?phone="+<?php echo $phone; ?>+ ""; 
   </script>
   <?php
    die();
} 
?>
```